# Getting the caret position in which textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, caret

I have a from with many of text box. Refer Photo.

[image: i1]

I created a numpad for my form. Refer photo.

[image: i2e]

Help me to code when click the numpad, the textbox which caret position now will appear.
As example, the caret now in Salesman Textbox, then when user click number 7, 7 will appear
in salesman textbox.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a numpad button, the caret will disappear from textbox. Hence we can't search for which textbox has caret, because no textbox has it. You can achieve this by saving last focused textbox in a variable, and output the number clicked to that textbox. This is the example of what I mean :

```
public TextBox FocusedTextBox;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;
    textBox2.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;
}

private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FocusedTextBox = (TextBox) sender;
}

private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FocusedTextBox != null) FocusedTextBox.Text += "7";
}
```